# Подскажите пожалуйста как переписать на новый ангуляр, не используя при этом css для показа меню

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<div class="dropdown-button" ng-if="$ctrl.organisations.length > 0" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleDropdown()"
    ng-class="{'dropdown-visible': $ctrl.showDropdown}"> // css component
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="8" viewBox="0 0 14 8">
       <path fill="#FFF" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.6 0L14 1.333 7 8 0 1.333 1.4 0 7 5.333z"></path>
   </svg>
</div>

<div class="list-wrapper" ng-if="$ctrl.showDropdown" ng-class="{'visible': $ctrl.showDropdown}">
   <div class="drowpdown-list">
       <div ng-repeat="organisation in $ctrl.organisations" class="list-item clearfix"
            ng-click="$ctrl.loginIntoOrganisation(organisation.id, $event);">
           <span class="organisation-name">
               {{organisation.type == 0 ? organisation.shortTitle || organisation.title : organisation.fullTitle}}
           </span>
           <span class="group-list">
               <span ng-repeat="groupTitle in organisation.groups" class="group">
                   {{groupTitle}}
               </span>
           </span>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="background" ng-if="$ctrl.showDropdown" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleDropdown()"></div>
```

Comment: вообще не вижу тут сложности, мне кажется 2 часа чтения документации и вы спокойно можете переписать сами 

Comment: Есть трудности...

Comment: `ng-if -> ngIf`, `ng-repeat -> ngFor`, `ng-click -> (click)`, `ng-class -> ngClass` и `$ctrl` не нужен :)

Comment: @overthesanity c этим я разобрался)Проблема в css, я не хочу запускаться через нее )

Comment: Не пойму, через кого запускаться? :)